# Can someone help me with this arc length integral?

Tags: integration

I need to solve this arc length integral for a polar function:

$r=3\cos^4(\frac{\theta}{2})$

$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-6\cos^3(\frac{\theta}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$

So the formula for the arc length of a polar function is:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{[\frac{dr}{d\theta}]^2+[r]^2} \,d\theta$

$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{[-6\cos^3(\frac{\theta}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})]^2+[3\cos^4(\frac{\theta}{2})]^2} \,d\theta$

Comment: You have two choices.  Either you need to use a formula for arc length in polar coordinates, or else you need to convert your equation to cartesian coordinates and use that cartesian formula.

Comment: I think $dx$ is just a typo? You wanted to say $d\theta$?

Comment: have you tried using the half angle formula

Comment: The integrand clearly simplifies to $$3\cos^3(\theta/2)\sqrt{4\sin^2(\theta/2)+\cos^2(\theta/2)}=3\cos^3(\theta/2)\sqrt{1+3\sin^2(\theta/2)}.$$ Then use the substitution $x=\sin(\theta/2)$ and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $$t=\frac{\theta}{2}$$

it becomes

$$L=6\int_0^\pi |\cos^3(t)|\sqrt{4\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)}dt$$

$$=6\int_0^\pi |\cos(t)|(1-\sin^2(t))\sqrt{1+3\sin^2(t)}dt$$

Comment: Yes,but that isn't solved completely

Comment: @MarceloEncisoJure divide the interval into $[0,pi/2]$ and $[pi/2,pi]$ and put $ \sin(t)=u$.